# How to know the end of int* array?

Tags: c, arrays, int

I'm making a dynamic array with `int*` data type using `malloc()`. But the problems is, how to know end of array?

There no an equivalent to `\0` for `int*` data type,so, how to do this? Pass size as out parameter of function?

Comment: You are using malloc() glob some memory like malloc(sizeof(int) * ELEMENTS) I suppose. Then you actually know that ELEMENTS in size, you can save the variable and pass it to your functions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C doesn't manage array lengths, as some other languages do.

you might consider a structure for this:

```
typedef struct t_thing {
  int* things;
  size_t count;
} t_thing;
```

in use:

```
t_thing t = { (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n), n };
```

Answer (score 10):

There is no "official" equivalent to `\0` for integers, but you can certainly use your own value. For example, if your integers represent distances then you can use -1 (not a valid distance) as a sentinel value to indicate the end of the array.

If your integer array can reasonably contain *any* `int` value, then you can pass back the size of the allocated array with an additional parameter to your function.

Comment: I like you idea. I will to use `#define EON EOF` too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NULL` as an end value. You can add an integer to a struct with the array that tracks the number of entries. Or you can track the size separately. You can do it however you want.

Comment: How would you possibly use NULL as the end value for an int[]?  The bytes 00 00 00 00 would just be interpreted as (int)0.

Comment: Exactly.  If no other value in the array contains 0, then you can use 0 as a terminator.

Comment: And if no other value contains 42, you can use 42.  The answer implies for me at least that `int` is somehow a nullable type, which of course it is not.

Comment: The OP was ambiguous about whether it's a dynamic array of `int *` values or a dynamic arrays of integer values pointed to by an `int *`. The use of `NULL` as a sentinel assumes it's an array of pointers. If not, you can use any value legal for the type that cannot be used inside the array. If there is no value that it not legal in the array, then you need to use another mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

C does not know where is the end of your dynamic array. you should remember the size that you allocate for the array.

Answer (score 1):

when u allocate memory with malloc, the number of bytes allocated is stored just before the start of the 'malloc'ated memory. if you know the size, you know the end as well!
This is explained in the bible of C, the K&R book. Wish I could give you the page number as well, but you'll know it when u see it.